# Adding item to LinkedList of ArrayLists size error

Tags: java, arraylist, size

Okey, in my program I created LinkedList of ArrayLists:

```
 List<Marker> list1 = new ArrayList<Marker>();
 LinkedList<List<Marker>> list2 = new LinkedList<List<Marker>>();
```

Everything works fine while adding items to list1: `list1.add(mark);`

But when I try to add my list1 to list2  ( `list2.add(list1)` ), I am getting strange things:
each list size in list2 becomes equals to last added list size+1, and i can't even read these lists items with (for example)     `list2.getFirst().get(0);`     - doing this I got error;

For example I am doing this:

```java
mark.addSomeInfo();
list1.add(mark);
list2.add(list1);
mark.addSomeInfo();
list1.add(mark);
list2.add(list1);
mark.addSomeInfo();
list1.add(mark);
list2.add(list1);
```

And I need to get this:

```
list2.get(0).size() = 1;
list2.get(1).size() = 2;
list2.get(2).size() = 3;
```

But instead I am getting this:

```
list2.get(0).size() = 4;
list2.get(1).size() = 4;
list2.get(2).size() = 4;
```

Why? What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LinkedList<List<Marker>> list2` `add` method does not create a copy of the list you added into it. It only adds a reference of `list1` to `list2`. So in essence your `list2` holds 3 references to the same list.

What you want to do is create the copies yourself as you are placing them into `list2`

```
mark.addSomeInfo();
list1.add(mark);
list2.add(new ArrayList<Mark>(list1));
mark.addSomeInfo();
list1.add(mark);
list2.add(new ArrayList<Mark>(list1));
mark.addSomeInfo();
list1.add(mark);
list2.add(new ArrayList<Mark>(list1));
```

Comment: And one more question. How about not adding items to list1 but just updating them and then put list1 to list2 as new element?

Comment: @user2595870 hmm if I understand correctly that won't work. The problem is that the `new ArrayList<Mark>(list1)` doesn't perform a deep copy. What this means is that you get a new list which contains the same objects as the old list. Whenever you change the state of an object, then all references that point to that object will get updated as well. To do what you want to do I would advise adding a copy constructor `Mark(Mark m)`. Then create a new list by iterating through the old one and adding copy constructed copies to the new list.

Comment: Yes, you undrestand me correctly. Now left just one problem - I am working with Google maps for android and I need to make marker clone, how to do this? Because Markers don't have copy/clone function.

Comment: Oh I don't know anything about google maps for android, it might be worth it to ask this as a new question. If the Markers have getters for internal values you could probably just write your own static copy function that takes a marker and returns a copied marker.

Answer (score 1):

All the reference of `LinkedList` refers to same `List` Object which is `list1` so it prints size 4.

As you used `ArrayList` which supports duplicate element so every time you add mark object it will make a duplicate entry.

Answer (score 1):

The references inside List2 are towards List1 .. This is why all the same SOP gives the same result 4

Answer (score 1):

`list1` is just a reference in your code.So in essence, you are adding the same `arraylist` object to the `linkedlist` again and again. And in the end the same `arraylist` is copied 3 times in your example and has size 4.

Answer (score 0):

At 0th,1st and 2nd position of list2, you have added same list1 object.
which is being changed by

```
 list1.add(mark);
```

As the above function has been called four times in your code.Hence list1 reference now points to the object on heap which has 4 items, and hence 
size of all 3 items of list1 has 4 elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
mark.addSomeInfo();
list1.add(mark);  //this gets added to list each time you add it --1
list2.add(list1); //this gets added too as many times as you add list1
mark.addSomeInfo();
list1.add(mark);  // 2
list2.add(list1);  //2
mark.addSomeInfo();
list1.add(mark);  // 3
list2.add(list1);  // 3
```

So after this you will have 3 elements in list1 and 3 lists in list2